# How to use proxy with telnetlib

Tags: python, telnetlib

Hello recently I started working with [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html) and now I need to route it through a proxy. I asked myself if there is a way to do that since you can also use proxies with `requests.get(proxies=)` for example?